# How to access key at any level?

Tags: json, nested, key, jq

I have this input file

```json
{
    "description": "this is a fake description",
    "owner": "john",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "topics": {
        "For collecting responses for prod1": {
            "suffix_name": "response-to-hogwarts.fifo",
            "tags": {}
        }
    },
    "queues": {
        "For collecting responses and requests from test1": {
            "suffix_name": "rr_sf_name.fifo",
            "tags": {}
        },
        "For collecting responses for test2": {
            "suffix_name": "response-to-hogwarts.fifo",
            "tags": {}
        }
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "For receiving harry_potter requests": {
            "topic": {
                "suffix_name": "harry_potter.fifo",
                "tag": "staging"
            },
            "queue": {
                "suffix_name": "rr_sf_name.fifo"
            }
        },
        "For receiving harry_potter requests from test3": {
            "topic": {
                "suffix_name": "harry_potter.fifo",
                "tag": "harry_potter_hogwarts"
            },
            "queue": {
                "suffix_name": "rr_sf_name.fifo"
            }
        },
        "For receiving demo requests": {
            "topic": {
                "suffix_name": "demo.fifo",
                "tag": "staging"
            },
            "queue": {
                "suffix_name": "rr_sf_name.fifo"
            }
        },
        "For receiving demo requests from test4 through connector": {
            "topic": {
                "suffix_name": "demo.fifo",
                "tag": "harry_potter_hogwarts"
            },
            "queue": {
                "suffix_name": "rr_sf_name.fifo"
            }
        },
        "For receiving testing responses for hogwarts": {
            "topic": {
                "suffix_name": "response-to-hogwarts.fifo"
            },
            "queue": {
                "suffix_name": "response-to-hogwarts.fifo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to remove the ".fifo" suffix from the value of **ALL** the `suffix_name` fields, at any level

Example output (truncated for brevity)

```json
    "topics": {
        "For collecting responses for prod1": {
            "suffix_name": "response-to-hogwarts",
            "tags": {}
        }
    },
```

Now I came up with this, which **is working** for me.

```
.queues |= with_entries(.value.suffix_name |= sub(".fifo";""))
| .topics |= with_entries(.value.suffix_name |= sub(".fifo";""))
| .subscriptions |= with_entries(.value |= with_entries(.value |= with_entries(.value |= rtrimstr(".fifo"))))
```

I want to know, if there is a better way, using recurse or something, to parse through all keys and if the key is `suffix_name`, trim the ".fifo" from the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `walk`:

```
walk(if type=="object" and .suffix_name 
     then .suffix_name |= sub("[.]fifo$";"") else . end)
```

Alternatively, just use `|=`:

```
 (.. | select(type == "object" and .suffix_name) | .suffix_name) 
  |=  sub("[.]fifo$";"")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to `walk` using the `path` functions - `getpath` and `setpath`

```
reduce ( paths | select(.[-1] | endswith("suffix_name")? ) ) as $p 
  ( .; setpath($p; getpath($p) | sub("[.]fifo$";"") ) )
```

Identify paths from the root to `suffix_name` and iterate it over using `reduce`. For each of the paths, reconstruct the value by having the suffix removed.